# Arabic word for door from root d-l-t or d-l-th

Tags: etymology, arabic, alphabets, semitic-languages

I know that the Hebrew letter 'daleth' originates from the word for 'door', indeed the Modern Hebrew word for door is 'dalet'.

Is there an Arabic word for door from this same root - d-l-t or d-l-th? Do we find it in the Qur'an or other Islamic literature?

Comment: I think the name of the letter *dal* would be a cognate

Comment: If it does exist it wouldn't be d-l-th, since Arabic *th* corresponds to Hebrew *sh*.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: I don't know of any, and haven't been able to find any.

Longer answer: the Hebrew word is דלת (*d-l-th*), pronounced *délet* in Modern Hebrew. Strong derives it from a root דלה (*d-l-h*) meaning "to swing"; Wiktionary doesn't link it to a root and instead says it goes back to Proto-Semitic **dalt* "door". It seems to be cognate with Akkadian *daltu* and Aramaic *dalthā*, which means regardless of anything else it's probably inherited rather than loaned.

The Arabic equivalent of Hebrew *d-l-th* would be *d-l-t*; Hebrew lost the Proto-Semitic `/θ/` (merging it into `/ʃ/`) and then gained it back through a sound change called "begadkefat spirantization". Arabic on the other hand kept almost all the original consonants and didn't do begadkefat spirantization. Long story short, a *th* in Hebrew (without exception?) corresponds to a *t* in Arabic.

Unfortunately, I've never heard of an Arabic word with the consonants *d-l-t*, and searching for دلت shows nothing relevant. If Strong is right, the root was actually *d-l-h*, but a search for that shows nothing relevant either.

Therefore, I feel relatively confident in saying that this root did not survive in Arabic.

Comment: Thank you. _Begadkefat spirantization_ is my new favorite curse word. "May you die of begadkefat spirantization before they even notice you're trying to speak Hebrew"

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ancient-hebrew.org/ancient-alphabet/dalet.htm

Check out this link. This shows that the earlier word for door in hebrew was dal and arabic does have root corresponding to it, and that root is faithfully preserved in the name of this letter in Arabic: Daal.

Comment: This does not answer the question about an Arabic cognate with the original meaning "door"